# the value visited by loc in dataframe was the previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use loc to get a certain value but the return number is the value before assignment. However, the  return value will be the current one if add square brackets around column names. I debug it for a long while, can someone help me

[jupyter notebook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkb1z.png)

7530 is the previous value and now it should be 10846.

I also tried iloc and it was no problem. I know that loc whose column name with square brackets will return a dataframe whereas the one without square brackets return a series, but I don't think  it would change the value.  What's more, the bug isn't always come out, just a few times in a for loop. It's in a large code and happened randomly so it's hard to reproduce the bug with easy code. I have tried so many times and it works right. I just want to know any possible reasons would cause the values of `dataframe.loc[row_name,[col_name]]` and `dataframe.loc[row_name,col_name]` to be different as shown in the figure.

Comment: Please provide the reproducible example.

Comment: if you have changed data you must reset kernels and run all cells it is possible problem i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I updated pandas from 1.4.2 to 1.5.2, the bug is gone. I ran the same code with two version of pandas and got different outcomes. Hence it's just a bug from old version of pandas.

[two outcomes with pandas 1.4.2 and 1.5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqYB.png)